# A Cunning Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

> You might view this riddle on my prefix,
>   It also comes with cheese,
>   My infix is the largest of my suffix,
>   I am a cunning scheme.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are a

> MACHINATION: machine, China, nation. I confess I'm not sure I understand the bit about cheese. Largest by *population*, of course.

EDITED to add:

> Some astute commenters point out that instead of viewing this on a *machine* you could view it on a *Mac* -- and then you have both the "big Mac and cheese" (a cheeseburger) and "mac and cheese" (a pasta dish). Thanks, @noedne and @MichaelMaggs!

Comment: Ah, clever. @MichaelMaggs might be rot13(znpnebav) too.

Comment: Yes, your edit in the second paragraph is what I was intending, the cheese was to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 3):

Partial

Prefix

> Mouse: mice eat cheese, and we may be viewing this with a mouse (computer)